# Записать результат работы функции в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть около 100 функций, которые в результате своей работы печатают в консоль много строк. Как в примере, но функции гораздо сложнее.

```
def print_lines(arg):
    for i in range(arg):
        print('line', i)
```

ВНЕЗАПНО, понадобилось выводить результат работы этих функций в файл. Есть ли какой-то способ сделать это проще чем дублировать каждую функцию с записью в файл вместо print() или с возвратом списка строк вместо print()?
Наверное правильно было изначально делать возврат списка строк. Но уже что есть то есть.

**UPD**
Решил вопрос так:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout 
def my_function(): 
    print('some text') 


with open('file_name.txt', 'w') as f: 
    with redirect_stdout(f): 
        my_function()
```

Comment: @Михаил-Муругов Добавил свое решение

Comment: @Михаил Муругов пока ньюансов не обнаружено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в самом начале переопределить функцию `print`

```py
old_print = print  # Запоминаем старую функцию print

def print(*args, **kwargs):  # Переопределяем
    if "file" not in kwargs:  # Если не передали параметр file
        with open("filename", "a") as fp:  # Будем записывать в файл filename
            old_print(*args, **kwargs, file=fp)
    else:
        old_print(*args, **kwargs)  # Иначе будем записывать в file, который передали
```

Но это **очень** плохая практика. Если кто-то будет смотреть Ваш код (возможно даже Вы сами через некоторое время), то Вам за это "спасибо" не скажут.

---

Другой способ: можно просто перенаправить stdout в файл. Для этого можно просто запустить скрипт так:

```
python script.py > filename
```

Тем самым всё будет печататься не в консоль, а в файл `filename`.

---

### UPD (уже неактуально, но пусть будет)

Если Вы хотите выполнить только одну функцию из скрипта, то придётся в самом скрипте подключать модуль `sys` (встроенный) и смотреть параметры, переданные скрипту из командой строки. Например:

```py
import sys


def func1(*args):
    print(args)  # Функционал функции


def func2(*args):
    print(args)  # Функционал функции

# ...

def run_all_funcs():  # запускает все функции
    func1()
    func2()
    # ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:  # Проверяем кол-во аргументов,
                            # переданных скрипту из командой строки
        if sys.argv[1] == "func1":
            func1()
        if sys.argv[1] == "func2":
            func2()
        # ...
    else:  # Если аргументов не передали, то запускаем все функции
        run_all_funcs()
```

И запуск тогда будет такой:

```
python script.py func2 > filename
```

Надеюсь, суть ясна.

---

### UUPD

Сразу не подумал, можно намного проще. Если в файле `script.py` есть функция `func(a, b)`, то только её можно вызвать так:

```
python -c "from script import *; func(1, 2)" > filename
```

Обратите внимание, что мы импортируем всё из файла `script.py`, но расширение `.py` не указываем.

Comment: А есть ли способ при таком варианте `python script.py > filename` передать определенной функции аргументы и вызвать результат только ее одной?

Comment: @Keymaster Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
def print_lines(arg):
    with open('out_file.txt', 'w')as f:
        for i in range(arg):
            print('line', i, file=f)


print_lines(5)
```

Comment: так придется все 100 функций редактироват. Вопрос как раз в том, как этого избежать.

Answer (score 1):

На один раз можно в самом начале переопределить функцию `print`:

```
def print(arg1, arg2):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(arg1), str(arg2))
```

После этого `print()` будет работать так, как написано в функции. Но нужно решить, как называть файл. Дата-время, например.

Но это плохое и грязное решение. Хотя рабочее.

Comment: Не универсальное решение. А если в каких-то функциях `print`'ы с доп параметрами (`sep`, `end` и т.д.)? Думаю, мысль Вы поняли.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да это понятно.